# WeeChat does not use IPv6

Tags: debian, ipv6, weechat

I have a [WeeChat](https://weechat.org/) version 1.5 installed on Debian 8.5 with `irc.server.freenode.ipv6` option set to `on`:

```
10:57:15  weechat     | [server] (irc.conf)
10:57:15  weechat     |   irc.server.freenode.ipv6 = on  (default: (undefined))
10:57:15  weechat     | 
10:57:15  weechat     | 1 option (matching with "irc.server.freenode.ipv6")
```

This should force WeeChat to prefer IPv6 over IPv4. irc.freenode.net has IPv6 AAAA records present:

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 -t AAAA irc.freenode.net +noall +short
chat.freenode.net.
2a00:1a28:1100:11::42
2a01:270:0:666f::1
2a01:7e00::f03c:91ff:fee2:413b
2001:6b0:e:2a18::118
$
```

..and for example I'm able to ping irc.freenode.net over IPv6:

```
$ ping6 -nc 4 irc.freenode.net
PING irc.freenode.net(2001:5a0:3604:1:64:86:243:181) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2001:5a0:3604:1:64:86:243:181: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=141 ms
64 bytes from 2001:5a0:3604:1:64:86:243:181: icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=141 ms
64 bytes from 2001:5a0:3604:1:64:86:243:181: icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=142 ms
64 bytes from 2001:5a0:3604:1:64:86:243:181: icmp_seq=4 ttl=51 time=142 ms

--- irc.freenode.net ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 141.567/141.903/142.081/0.431 ms
$
```

However, when I try to connect to irc.freenode.net in WeeChat, then IPv6 is not even tried (checked with `tcpdump`). Even if I reject connections on IPv4 to TCP port 6667, then IPv6 is not tried.

I assume that the problem is not with the WeeChat (I even tried with different versions). Any ideas, what might cause such behavior?

Comment: i found this issue tracker, https://github.com/weechat/weechat/issues/558

Comment: I also read that but I don't use IPv6 address from `fd00::/8` allocation. I have a global unicast IPv6 address which is used as a source IPv6 address(confirmed with `ip -6 route get 2001:5a0:3604:1:64:86:243:181`).

Comment: Does `telnet -6 irc.freenode.net 6667` connect correctly?

Comment: @MartinSugioarto Yes. I see `Trying 2001:6b0:e:2a18::118...`, `Connected to chat.freenode.net.`, `:leguin.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Checking Ident`, `:leguin.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Found your hostname`, etc messages.

Comment: Did you take a look if the [answers about the address resolution precedence](http://askubuntu.com/q/32298) help you?

Comment: It appears obvious at this point, that the problem _is_ with WeeChat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try with weechat 1.6-rc2 (current devel version)?
I fixed a bug with host address during connection to servers.
By the way, version 1.6 is scheduled in 2 days.